# Application of function after arithmetic operations

Tags: awk

How to write in print that program should first count and then apply t function? I would like to have result with six decimal places that are cut, not round. Thank you.

```
  /^$/ { flag=0; next; }
/D Format/ { flag=0; next; }
/F Format/ { flag=1; next; }
/^ 9 / { print t($5) "\n" t($6);  } 
/^10 / { print t($5) "\n" t($6);  } 
/^11 / { print t($5*180/3.141592653589) "\n" t($6*180/3.141592653589);  }
/^15 / { print t($5*100) "\n" t($6*100);  }
/^16 / { print t($5) "\n" t($6);  } 
/^20 / { print t($5*10) "\n" t($6*10);  }
/^23 / { print t($5) "\n" t($6);  } 
/^24 / { print t($5) "\n" t($6);  }
function t(n, s) {
s=index(n,".");
return (s ? substr(n,1,s+6) : n);
}
```

Input is

```
 SUM OF ABSOLUTE VALUES OF CHECKS IS 0.844670D-13


                      Input-Output in F Format

No.  Curve    Input Param.        Correction     Output Param.    Standard Deviation
 9      0     43.8999000000     -0.2148692026     43.6850307974      0.1066086900
10      0      0.0883000000     -0.0081173828      0.0801826172      0.0006755954
11      0      2.5816650000      0.1530838229      2.7347488229      0.0114687081
15      0      0.2175000000      0.0018561462      0.2193561462      0.0017699976
16      0     80.4198910000      3.4449399961     83.8648309961      0.1158732928
20      0      1.9424000000      0.3078499311      2.2502499311      0.0047924544
23      0      3.5047300000      0.4315780848      3.9363080848      0.0052905759
24      0      5.5942300000      1.8976306735      7.4918606735      0.0092102115
26      0  54804.4046000000     -0.0029799077  54804.4016200923      0.0006133608


                      Input-Output in D Format

No.  Curve    Input Param.        Correction     Output Param.    Standard Deviation
 9      0  0.4389990000D+02 -0.2148692026D+00  0.4368503080D+02  0.1066086900D+00
10      0  0.8830000000D-01 -0.8117382819D-02  0.8018261718D-01  0.6755954153D-03
11      0  0.2581665000D+01  0.1530838229D+00  0.2734748823D+01  0.1146870812D-01
15      0  0.2175000000D+00  0.1856146162D-02  0.2193561462D+00  0.1769997586D-02
16      0  0.8041989100D+02  0.3444939996D+01  0.8386483100D+02  0.1158732928D+00
20      0  0.1942400000D+01  0.3078499311D+00  0.2250249931D+01  0.4792454358D-02
23      0  0.3504730000D+01  0.4315780848D+00  0.3936308085D+01  0.5290575930D-02
24      0  0.5594230000D+01  0.1897630674D+01  0.7491860674D+01  0.9210211480D-02
26      0  0.5480440460D+05 -0.2979907673D-02  0.5480440162D+05  0.6133608199D-03
```

I would like to get like output

```
43.685030
0.106608
0.080182
0.000675
156.68965
0.657068
21.935614
0.176999
83.864830
0.115873
22.502499
0.047924
3.936308
0.005290
7.491860
0.009210
```

that are numbers from 5. and 6. column from the first table except row starting 26.

But I am getting instead of that these numbers (mistakes are in format - 2 decimal places instead of 6 and printing numbers from both tables instead of one)

```
43.685030
0.106608
0.080182
0.000675
156.69
0.657109
21.9356
0.177
83.864830
0.115873
22.5025
0.047924
3.936308
0.005290
7.491860
0.009210
0.436850
0.106608
0.801826
0.675595
15.669
6.57109
21.9356
17.7
0.838648
0.115873
2.25025
4.79245
0.393630
0.529057
0.749186
0.921021
```

[image]

Comment: I added the required output. Thank you

Comment: You seem to have buried your question in a ton of code plus data. [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of whatever **the problem** is that you're asking for help with instead of a vague question that sounds just like your previous questions and then just a dump of everything you have so far. The code you're executing should do exactly what you're asking to do so I can't imagine what **the problem** is you're trying to solve.

Comment: I am sorry I editted the question again, I hope it's clear now

Comment: If you don't want to print the contents of the 2nd table then just change `/D Format/{next}` to `/D Format/{exit}`. I updated my answer to add a script that does that.

Comment: Thank you and is it possible to add to code something like /F Format/ to /D Format/ - real input file is larger.

Comment: It's only software so anything is possible but all we can do is help you with the questions you ask about given the information you provide in your question and THAT wasn't mentioned anywhere. Please accept an answer to the question you asked and then ask a new question if you have one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm taking a guess here - is the problem you're trying to solve that you expect greater precision from this calculation?

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { print t(2.7347488229 * 180 / 3.141592653589) }
function t(n,     s) {
    s=index(n,".")
    return (s ? substr(n,1,s+6) : n)
}

$ awk -f tst.awk
156.69
```

If so then note the effect of setting CONVFMT to a higher value than the precision you want to end up with after the truncation:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { print t(2.7347488229 * 180 / 3.141592653589) }
function t(n,     s) {
    CONVFMT="%0.17f"
    s=index(n,".")
    return (s ? substr(n,1,s+6) : n)
}

$ awk -f tst.awk
156.689565
```

That works because the effect of substr() is to convert the number to a string and at that point the value of CONVFMT is applied, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Strings-And-Numbers.

You could set CONVFMT in the BEGIN section but I set it next to where its effect is needed so you can tweak to not impact the rest of the script if you like:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { print t(2.7347488229 * 180 / 3.141592653589) }
function t(n,     s, origConvfmt) {
    origConvfmt=CONVFMT
    CONVFMT="%0.17f"
    s=index(n,".")
    return (s ? substr(n,1,s+6) : n)
    CONVFMT=origConvfmt
}

$ awk -f tst.awk
156.689565
```

Finally - to get rid of redundancy consider rewriting your script as:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { CONVFMT="%0.17f" }

!NF { flag=0 }
$NF == "Format" { flag=($NF-1 == "F" ? 1 : 0) }

$1 !~ /^[0-9]+$/ { next }

$1 == 11 { prt(180,3.141592653589); next }
$1 == 15 { prt(100,1); next }
$1 == 20 { prt(10,1); next }
$1 != 26 { prt(1,1) }

function prt(mult, div) {
    print trunc($5 * mult / div) ORS trunc($6 * mult / div)
}

function trunc(n,       s) {
    s=index(n,".")
    return (s ? substr(n,1,s+6) : n)
}
```

---

**EDIT 1**
Given your updated requirement to not print the contents of the 2nd table:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {  CONVFMT="%0.17f" }

/D Format/ { exit }

$1 !~ /^[0-9]+$/ { next }

$1 == 11 { prt(180,3.141592653589); next }
$1 == 15 { prt(100,1); next }
$1 == 20 { prt(10,1); next }
$1 != 26 { prt(1,1) }

function prt(mult, div) {
    print trunc($5 * mult / div) ORS trunc($6 * mult / div)
}

function trunc(n,       s) {
    s=index(n,".")
    return (s ? substr(n,1,s+6) : n)
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
43.685030
0.106608
0.080182
0.000675
156.689565
0.657108
21.935614
0.176999
83.864830
0.115873
22.502499
0.047924
3.936308
0.005290
7.491860
0.009210
```

Comment: Thank you and what does this means? cat tst.awk

Comment: You're welcome. `cat` is a UNIX command that, among other things, can display the contents of a file. `tst.awk` is such a file. Try typing `man cat` or google "UNIX cat".

Comment: Thank you for your codes it solved the problem with formates. And please, how to solve : 156.689565
0.657108
2.734748
0.011468 are printing number, but I would like to print only the two - these calculated. The same problem is 21.935614
0.176999
0.219356
0.001769 and 22.502499
0.047924
2.250249
0.004792. And then I would like to print numbers ONLY from the first table.

Comment: I'm sorry I have no idea what you're asking about. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Thank you for update and how to get rid of yellow numbers in the new picture from my question?

Comment: That requirement is extremely unclear (how would a script know which are the "yellow" numbers?) but in any case [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/361691) are highly frowned upon. Always: If you have a followup question then accept an answer to the question you originally asked and then ask a new question if you have one and this time provide a clear, concise, testable [mcve] about **the problem** you're asking for help with.

Comment: I ask if it is possible to replace number from table with number, that is a result of operation with this number.

Comment: Again - I'm sorry but I don't know what that means, ask a new question.

Comment: OK, I am sorry, thank you very much for your patience and advise. I create a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53906573/awk-restricting-area-in-file-printing Is it cleaner?

Comment: What does CONVFMT do please? How it set a format? Thank you

Comment: You've GOT to start googling and/or reading man pages. I even gave you a direct link to the specific entry in the man page for this one. Re-read my answer and click on the link I provided.